# Ordered/Unordered List With Multiple Columns

Tags: html, css

This isn't a question on how to use columns on lists, but rather the alignment of the columns on my site.

My code:

```
<ol class="threecolumns">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>

<style>
.threecolumns {column-count: 3;}
</style>
```

Using codepen, I get the expected result (sorry for the rudimentary example):

1. Item 1    3. Item 3    5. Item 5
2. Item 2    4. Item 4

My site outputs it like this:

1. Item 1    2. Item 2    4. Item 4
                 3. Item 3    5. Item 5

I am using MadCap Flare as the publishing engine. I can't see anything in the CSS for the ol/ul that would cause this though.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to create a three-column layout using an ordered list. The CSS property `column-count` can be used to achieve this. However, it seems that you are having trouble with the alignment of the columns. One possible solution is to use `display: flex` on the ordered list. Another solution is to use float on the list items. You can also try using display: inline-block on the list items.

Comment: `.threecolums {display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; ;list-style-position:inside;}` and ` .threecolumns li {width: 33%;}` works, but is not the ideal solution that I wanted. I would like to figure out why I'm getting this layout on my site when I can't replicate it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My stylesheet also included
`li {margin: 8px 0;}` which comes from MadCap Flare's default styles.
This seems to break the flow of the list items.
After removing that margin the ordered list operates as expected.